# want to filter model objects by email, however filtering is not working in Django REST api

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have my API in Django REST Framework:

Here is my models.py:

```
class myModel(models.Model):
    user_email = models.CharField(max_length= 200, null= False)
```

Here is my views.py:

```
class GetItemsByEmail(generics.ListAPIView):
   def get_queryset(self):
       email_items = self.request.query_params.get("user_email")
       if(email_items is not None):
          itemsReturned =  myModel.objects.all().filter(user_email = email_items)
          return Response(data= itemsReturned)
```

Here is my urls.py:

```
url_patterns = [
   path('users/account=<str:id>/items', GetItemsByEmail.as_view()),
   ]
```

**My Question:**

I am getting an empty list, getting nothing from making an API call to the above endpoint.
I want to get all the items in the database associated with a particular email, but the filter is not working ?
What is the reason behind that ?

Comment: for filtering based on a condition on django models, you need to use the following form

`myModel.objects.filter(user_email = email_items)`

don't use .all() in case of filtering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined the parameter in the URL, so this is an URL parameter. `request.query_params` is however not determined by the path, but by the [*query string* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

You obtain URL parameters through `self.kwargs`, so:

```
class GetItemsByEmail(generics.ListAPIView):
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        #    use self.kwargs ↓
        email_items = self.kwargs.get('user_email')
        if email_items is not None:
            return myModel.objects.filter(user_email=email_items)
        else:
            # return some queryset
            pass
```

Your `urls.py` should be updated to work with `user_email`, not `id`:

```
url_patterns = [
   path('users/account=<str:user_email>/items', GetItemsByEmail.as_view()),
]
```

While it is not impossible, it is not very common to have an equal sign in the URL, nor to include an email address, these are typically done through the query string or in case of non-GET requests in the payload of the request or the headers.